# outlook vsto how to add width for listviewItem

Tags: outlook, vsto

I have list of data need display on the custom pane.
I'm using `ListView`.

How could I change each individual `ListViewItem` width?
I cannot find the `ListViewItem` style in the `ListView`.

Any recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Find out myself.

// check full details of the item in the list and set the row can be selected

caseList.View = View.Details;

caseList.FullRowSelect = true;